# How can an Ansible play be contingent on whether the previous postgresql_db play created a database?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook for setting up an Ubuntu web development box. If my Ansible `postgresql_db` play finds that the database has not been created yet and creates it, then I would like to run a subsequent shell command to do a bit of extra database setup. I was expecting this to work (here the shell command is just a dummy command, written so that it is easy to tell if it ran):

```
  - name: Create database
    become: yes
    become_user: postgres
    register: database_creation
    postgresql_db: name=mydatabase

  - name: Example conditional command
    when: database_creation.uchanged
    shell: date > /tmp/tmp
```

I was expecting `uchanged` to be available as an attribute in the `when:` expression because if I echo the `database_creation` value I get (in the case where the database is already created):

```
{uchanged: False, udb: mydatabase}
```

But in fact the `when:` clause shown above explodes with the error:

```
==> default: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg":
"ERROR! The conditional check 'database_creation.uchanged' failed.
The error was: ERROR! error while evaluating conditional
(database_creation.uchanged): ERROR! 'dict object' has no attribute
'uchanged'\n\nThe error appears to have been in
'/vagrant/develop/playbook.yml': line 82, column 5, but may\nbe
elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe
offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: test\n    ^ here\n"}
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct syntax for accessing the `uchanged` attribute of `database_creation` so that I can make the subsequent play contingent upon it? Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `unchanged` you need to use `not changed`.

```
when: not database_creation | changed
```

In general you should better be using the notation `variable | changed` instead of `variable.changed`. `.changed` is not wrong but it is better to use the [available filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-often-used-with-conditionals). [The filter](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ec95f50cb6ea48810b737993e4db3672846b31ab/lib/ansible/plugins/test/core.py#L41) would also take care of checking possible nested results. (generated by loops)

Comment: Perfect — thanks! The leading `u` confused me about whether the value I saw in the dictionary really corresponded to the filter or not, but I have just tested and got exactly the behavior you described. Since, as it happens, I want the database command to only fire if the database creation *does* run, the expression I've wound up using is: `when: database_creation | changed`

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I misread that for `unchanged`. Not sure about the leading `u`. In Python a leading `u` indicates a unicode object. But I have never seen that in this situation. How did you output the registered dict? Did you run a  task like `- debug: var=database_creation` ?

Comment: No, I didn't know about debug yet so I did something ad-hoc like `shell: echo '{{ database_creation }}' > /tmp/output.txt`